# Push an object with a variable as a property name onto an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript array and a variable. I want to push onto the array an object with the variable as the property name, but it must hold the value of the variable, not the variable as a string.
If I have this code:

```
array = [];
var x = 10;
array.push({x: y});
```

The x is stored as a string "x", not a variable that contains the value of var x.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The property name in an object literal is not evaluated as a variable. You have to assign the property using bracket notation.

```
var obj = {};
obj[x] = y;
array.push(obj);
```

Comment: With ES6, this can be done more succinctly `{[x]: y}`